# Merge two dicts in separate list by id

Tags: python, arrays, merge

I'm trying to merge the object based on key `specs`, most of the keys structure is consistent, taking into consideration the merge will only happen if `company_name` is the same (in this example, I only have one `company_name`) and if *only* (name,  {color, type, license, description) are equal across multiple lists.

```
[
{
    "company_name": "GreekNLC",
    "metadata": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "details": [
                {
                    "color": "black",
                    "type": "bmw",
                    "license": "4DFLK",
                    "specs": [
                        {
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "sedan",
                                        "germany"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "drive",
                                        "expensive"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "description": "amazing car"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "car_details": [
                {
                    "color": "black",
                    "type": "bmw",
                    "license": "4DFLK",
                    "specs": [
                        {
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "powerful",
                                        "convertable"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "drive",
                                        "expensive"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "description": "amazing car"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I expect the following output:

```
[
{
    "company_name": "GreekNLC",
    "metadata": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "details": [
                {
                    "color": "black",
                    "type": "bmw",
                    "license": "4DFLK",
                    "specs": [
                        {
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "powerful",
                                        "convertable"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "sedan",
                                        "germany"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "info": [
                                        "drive",
                                        "expensive"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "description": "amazing car"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Code I have so far,

```
headers = ['color', 'license', 'type', 'description']

def _key(d):
  return [d.get(i) for i in headers]

def get_specs(b):
  _specs = [c['properties'] for i in b for c in i['specs']]
  return [{"properties": [i for b in _specs for i in b]}]

def merge(d):
  new_merged_list = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in groupby(sorted(d, key=_key), key=_key)]
  k = [{**dict(zip(headers, a)), 'specs': get_specs(b)} for a, b in new_merged_list]
  return k

result = {'name': merge(c.get("details")) for i in data for c in i.get("metadata")}

print(json.dumps(result))
```

but it does not work. I'm getting this

```
{"name": [{"color": "black", "specs": [{"properties": [{"info": 
["amazing", "strong"]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` metod requires an string arg, you are passing a list object. You have just corrected it :)

Comment: Yep, but I'm still not seeing the expected output above. can you help please  @scriptmonster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you're looking to perform is similar to a grouping by:
`company_name`, `name`, `color`, `type`, `license` and `description`.

You can make a tuple of all cars as key-value pairs and perform a set operation on the resulting tuple, group by the compound key and rebuild the list.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from collections.abc import Hashable

def merge_spec_props(company_data):
    keyed_tuples = (
                ((
                co['company_name'],
                user['name'], 
                car_detail['color'], 
                car_detail['type'], 
                car_detail['license'],
                car_detail['description'],
                ), (
                    (k, v 
                    if isinstance(v, Hashable)
                    else tuple(v))
                    for k, v in prop.items()
                    )
                )
                for co in company_data
                for user in co['metadata']
                for car_detail in user['car_details']
                for spec in car_detail['specs']
                for prop in spec['properties'] 
                for k, v in prop.items()
                )
    uniq = set(keyed_tuples)
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for k, spec in uniq:
        grouped[k].append(spec)

    merged_lst = [
        {
            'company_name': company_name, 
            'metadata': [{
                'name': username,
                'car_details': [{
                        'color': car_color,
                        'type': car_type,
                        'license': car_license,
                        'specs': [dict(spec)
                            for spec in specs
                        ],
                        'description': desc
                }]
            }]
        }
        for (company_name, username, car_color, car_type, car_license, desc), specs in grouped.items()
    ]

    return merged_lst
```

While this implementation is very specific to your data and possibly this function can as no reusable value for another kind of data. 
If `description` were different in any of `car_details`, only the latest would be entered in a different company.

It's noteworthy to mention that this doesn't merge on intermediate fields. A possible way to go is to convert the data into a tree and do a postorder transversal to get the merged structure.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks @Oluwafemi Sule. one quick question though, along with `{ "info": [ "sedan",  "germany" ]}` sometimes I have `{ "info": [ "sedan",  "germany" ], "tire_size": "2.45.6"}` I get the `tire_size` item in the following output format `"tire_size": ['2','45','6']` which is not what I expected. why did that happen? I expect output to be `{ "info": [ "sedan",  "germany" ], "tire_size": "2.45.6"}`

Comment: That's because it's converted to a tuple. If you have more than a single field in the spec, the last iteration needs to be moved close to the key-value tuple pair. You could check if it's hashable before converting to a tuple. I have updated the answer to reflect this handling.